# I couldnt find any- "comment" / "uncomment" icons/images in the VS2010ImageLibrary, can anyone help me?

Tags: visual-studio, icons, comments

I am searching for icons/images for my application.. especially for the menu and toolbar..
i am looking for the following icons/images (16x16 if possible):
1. comment
2. uncomment
this icons can be found in the IDE of Visual Studio (comment/uncomment lines)

I am asking this because for some reason I couldn't find any of this icons in the "VS2010ImageLibrary" which ships with Visual Studio 2010

Thanks in advance,
Din

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those icons are probably copy right protected, a much better option would be to use a Royalty-Free image site like [www.istockphoto.com](http://www.istockphoto.com)

That way you can't get sued.

Answer (score 2):

In the time you spent looking for those icons, you could have easily rolled your own!  Those two icons are mostly a bunch of straight lines.

You could make your own icons that also make even more sense that Microsoft's.  For example:

//
<s>//</s>

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.freeiconsweb.com/ as well.